Proving the sequence sastifying a specific property is bounded

Let $a_1, a_2,...$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Assume that for
any positive integers $k,l,m,n$ satisfying $k + n = m + l,$ we have the following equality $$ \dfrac{a_{k}
 + a_{n}}{1 + a_{k}a_{n}} = \dfrac{a_{m} + a_{l}}{1 + a_{m}a_{l}}.$$
Show that there exist positive numbers $b, c$ so that $b\leq  a_{n} \leq c$ for any positive integer $n.$

I still don't have any idea how to start this problem.
I just notice that $$ \dfrac{(a_{k}+1)(a_{n}+1)}{1 + a_{k}a_{n}} = \dfrac{(a_{m} +1)( a_{l}+1)}{1 + a_{m}a_{l}}.$$
Also, since $n+1+n-1=n+n$, I have $$\dfrac{a_{n-1}+1}{a_n+1}\dfrac{a_{n+1}+1}{a_n+1}=\dfrac{1+a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}{1+a^2_{n}}$$
I don't know how to continue :(
Any help I would be super appreciated.

@KaleBhodre yes

@KaleBhodre I edited above

For $(k, n, l, m) = (i, i+2, i+1, i+1)$ we get
$$ 
 \frac{a_{i}+a_{i+2}}{1+a_{i}a_{i+2}} = \frac{2a_{i+1}}{1+a_{i+1}^2} \, .
$$
Multiplying both sides with $(-1)$ and adding $1$ gives
$$ 
 \frac{(1-a_{i})(1-a_{i+2})}{1+a_{i}a_{i+2}} = \frac{(1-a_{i+1})^2}{1+a_{i+1}^2} \, .
$$
If $a_i = 1$ for some $i$ then the last identity shows that $a_{i+1} = 1$, and consequently $a_j = 1$ for $j \ge i$, and the desired lower and upper bound exist.
So from now on we assume that $a_i \ne 1$ for all $i$. Then the last identity shows that $(1-a_{i})(1-a_{i+2}) > 0$ for all $i$, which means that

either $a_1, a_3, a_5, \ldots$ are all less than one,
or $a_1, a_3, a_5, \ldots$ are all greater than one,

and also

either $a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots$ are all less than one,
or $a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots$ are all greater than one.

Let us first consider the case that $0 < a_{2i} < 1$ for all $i$. Then  the real numbers $x_i = \tanh^{-1}(a_{2i})$ (inverse hyperbolic tangent) are defined and positive. Using the addition theorem for the hyperbolic tangent we get
$$
 \tanh(x_{i} + x_{i+2}) = \frac{a_{2i}+a_{2i+4}}{1+a_{2i}a_{2i+4}} = \frac{2a_{2i+2}}{1+a_{2i+2}^2} = \tanh(2 x_{i+1})
$$
and therefore $x_{i} + x_{i+2} = 2 x_{i+1}$ for all $i$. But this means that $(x_i)$ is a linear sequence, and since all $x_i$ are positive, the sequence must be nondecreasing. Then $(a_{2i})$ is nondecreasing as well, and we have
$$
 0 < a_2 \le a_{2i} < 1
$$
for all $i$.
If $a_{2i} > 1$ for all $i$ then define $x_i = \tanh^{-1}(1/a_{2i})$ instead. Again $x_{i} + x_{i+2} = 2 x_{i+1}$ for all $i$, $(x_i)$ is nondecreasing, and now we conclude that $(a_{2i})$ is nonincreasing, i.e.
$$
 1 < a_{2i} \le a_2 < \infty
$$
for all $i$.
In the same way one shows that either
$$
 0 < a_1 \le a_{2i-1} < 1
$$
for all $i$, or
$$
 1 < a_{2i-1} \le a_1 < \infty
$$
for all $i$, and that finishes the proof.
